# For $|z| < 1 \; \sum_{0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z} $. Also find all the values of $z$ for which the given series diverges.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$. Show that for $|z| < 1 \; \sum_{0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z} $. Also find all the values of $z$ for which the given series diverges.

Consider the partial sum $$s(n) = 1 + z + z^2 +\ldots + z^{n-1} = \frac{z^n - 1}{z-1} \to  \frac1{1-z} \text{ if } |z | < 1 \text{ because } z^n \to 0 $$

Also, let $R$ be the radius of convergence of the given series, then
$$ \frac1R = \lim \sup |1|^{1/n} = 1 \rightarrow R = 1$$

Hence, the series diverges for $|z| > 1$

How can I check the convergence/divergence on the unit circle $|z| = 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|z|=1$, then $|z^n|=1$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Therefore, you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}z^n=0$, which implies that the series diverges.

Comment: that's not true. it does not converge, but it does not mean it diverges

Comment: @Exodd Yes, it does. It is not my fault if you don't know what divergence means. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) for instance.

Comment: we have different definitions of divergent. The same page, in other languages, reports different definition

Comment: Did you downvote me because we use different definitions? Besides, the Spanish and the French versions of that article use the same definition. Which language do you have in mind?

Comment: I did because I did not know there was a different definition

Comment: So I suppose that you see no problem if I downvote your answer, since you use a definition different from mine. Am I right?

Comment: I tried to remove the downvote, but the system blocked me, I don't know why "You last voted on this answer 14 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: @Exodd Try again. I've edited my answer and so the system will not block you now.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For any complex $ z$, we have

$$|z|=1 \iff \;(\exists t\in \Bbb R)\; :\; z=e^{it}$$

Now, by geometric sum, compute

$$1+(e^{it})+(e^{it})^2+...+(e^{it})^{n-1}=$$

$$\frac{1-e^{nit}}{1-e^{it}}=$$

$$e^{\frac{n-1}{2}it}\frac{\sin(\frac{nt}{2})}{\sin(\frac t2)}$$

Answer (score 1):

For $z=1$, it is easy to show that it diverges.

If $z\ne 1$, then
$$s(n) = 1 + z + z^2 +\ldots + z^{n-1} = \frac{z^n - 1}{z-1}$$
still holds, and $z^n$ is a complex number on the unit circle that does not converge and does not diverge, but oscillates.

In conclusion, the series diverges iff $|z|>1$ or $z=1$.